# In Shor's algorithm, what is the exact analysis of its time and probability complexity?

Tags: complexity-theory, shors-algorithm

Generally exact complexities aren't interesting, but I couldn't find any info on it for this case at all.

Specifically my question, is let's say I have a polynomial p(n) and I want to have a quantum Turing machine that solves factorization at at most p(n)/c steps s.t. it has an error probability of at most `2^(-p(n))`, what is the maximum c I can get? What if I expand the question to c being a function of n, can this be done for c(n)=n?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to QCSE.  A lot of people have given a lot of thought to how long it would take to *explicitly* execute Shor's algorithm on a cryptographically relevant problem.

One fantastic paper by Gidney and Ekerå is [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.09749).  There, they give a polynomial number of Toffoli/CCNOT gates to factor an $n$-bit number as $0.3n^3$ and a circuit depth of $500n^2$.  So, I guess you can say that the constant prefactor for the number of Toffoli gates are $0.3$, while the constant prefactor for the depth is $500$.

And yes, Shor's algorithm is "probabilistic" insofar as, even running on error-free logical qubits with error-free gates we will get a random output for each run of the QFT, but that's why we are always concerned with the *expected* number of runs and the number of times we have to run the QFT to get an output, to feed into the other classical portions (the continued-fraction portion) of Shor's algorithm.